# Access environment variables from Foxx

Tags: arangodb, foxx

Is there something like node’s process.env to access environment variables? I want to know in my Foxx code whether it's running in development, test, staging, or production.

Alternatively, is there any way to determine if my Foxx app is running in development-mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we have thought about a getenv wrapper several times, I guess now its time to implement it. It may be in time for 2.5.1, we'll see ;-)

The foxx self debug awareness can be achieved via: applicationContext.isDevelopment

As noted above, arangodb now [contains the `process.env` functionality](https://docs.arangodb.com/latest/Manual/Appendix/JavaScriptModules/) similar to nodejs.

Comment: Thanks. I've opened an issue on Github.

Comment: github link: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1281. I think so everyone who is interested can follow the discussion